# How to loop until a certain button is pressed using pynput?

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

My current code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import threading
import datetime, time
import os
import subprocess

keyboard = Controller()

def loading():
    os.system("open /System/Applications/TextEdit.app")
    time.sleep(1)
    while running:
        keyboard.press("a")
        
def on_press(key):
    global running  # inform function to assign (`=`) to external/global `running` instead of creating local `running`

    if key == keyboard.Key.left:
        running = True
        # create thread with function `loading`
        t = threading.Thread(target=loading)
        # start thread
        t.start()
        
    if key == keyboard.Key.down:
        # to stop loop in thread
        running = False

    if key == keyboard.Key.right:
        # stop listener
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Im trying to loop keyboard presses, but stop when right or down key is pressed, but I'm getting an error of "'Controller' object has no attribute 'Listener'". My code works when I don't include the listener part, so I'm not exactly sure how to combine them together to make a cohesive program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrote `from pynput import keyboard` and then after that, `keyboard = Controller()`, so the same variable `keyboard` then refers to your instance of Controller, and not the module pynput.keyboard (which is what actually has the Listener class in it)

You can use a different name for that, while instantiating it and then wherever else you use it, such as inside loading(), then the code will work.

- Note: Using a loop with no delay like `while True: keyboard.press('a')` is an *absolutely* ***dangerous*** idea - I've had my computer completely hang, with no response , because of statements like that - and had to shut it down by force to be able to continue doing anything. It's better to include a `time.sleep` there too.